# Make a transfer inline

Tags: smart-contract, eosio.token, action, transfer

I would like to send SYS token owned by the smart contract account to a third party account when anyone call a specific action. I have tried the following code but I am getting an error:

```
[[eosio::action]]
void sendtoalice() {
    // make an inline transfer to alice
    action transferAlice = action(
        permission_level{get_self(),"active"_n},
        "eosio.token"_n,
        "transfer"_n,
        std::make_tuple(get_self(), "alice", "0.0001 SYS", "")
         );

    transferAlice.send();
}
```

Error:

```
$ cleos push action mycontract sendtoalice '[]' -p bob@active
Error 3090003: Provided keys, permissions, and delays do not satisfy declared authorizations
Ensure that you have the related private keys inside your wallet and your wallet is unlocked.
Error Details:
transaction declares authority '{"actor":"mycontract","permission":"active"}', but does not have signatures for it under a provided delay of 0 ms, provided permissions [{"actor":"mycontract","permission":"eosio.code"}], provided keys [], and a delay max limit of 3888000000 ms
pending console output:
```

Any idea of what could be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to transfer tokens, which requires `mycontract@active` permission. But when you send tokens from within a contract, the permission is `mycontract@eosio.code` - even if you sign the transaction with your `mycontract@active` key.

There are then two problems with the example you post:

1. You sign the action with `bob@active`, it should be `mycontract@active`.
2. You need to add `mycontract@eosio.code` permission to the active permissions. To do that, type the following into the terminal:

```
cleos set account permission mycontract active '{"threshold": 1, "keys":[{"key":"MYCONTRACT_PUBLIC_KEY", "weight":1}], "accounts":[{"permission":{"actor":"mycontract","permission":"eosio.code"},"weight":1}], "waits":[] }' owner -p mycontract
```

This allows the active key to be satisfied by either the private key that currently belongs to the active permission, OR it also allows any of the code in the mycontract smart contract to act with active permission.

## Allowing a contract to act on your behalf

If Bob wants to transfer money through this smart contract, then he needs to give the contract permission to use his active permission:

```
cleos set account permission bob active '{"threshold": 1, "keys":[{"key":"BOB_PUBLIC_KEY", "weight":1}], "accounts":[{"permission":{"actor":"mycontract","permission":"eosio.code"},"weight":1}], "waits":[] }' owner -p bob
```

Then, the code of the contract would be changed as follows:

```
[[eosio::action]]
void sendtoalice() {
    // make an inline transfer to alice
    require_auth(eosio::name("bob"));
    action transferAlice = action(
        permission_level{get_self(),"active"_n},
        "eosio.token"_n,
        "transfer"_n,
        std::make_tuple("bob", "alice", "0.0001 SYS", "")
         );

    transferAlice.send();
}
```

Comment: Is my use case impossible to implement? I would like to make some action triggered by someone sending SYS from the contract to a third party?

Comment: I confirm that I would like to use bob (a regular user) and not mycontract to call the action.

Comment: I updated my answer to show how the smart contract could send money from Bob's account

Comment: Thanks. However, I want to transfer the contract tokens and not Bob's tokens.

Comment: Then what does bob have to do with anything? In any case, you just change the first argument of the `make_tuple` to `_self` if you want bob to send tokens from the smart contract to someone else

Comment: The first argument of the make_tuple is already _self in my question. I want Bob to call the contract, and the contract to send the contract's money to Alice.

Comment: So set the permission as I show in my first part of my answer: `cleos set account permission mycontract active '{"threshold": 1, "keys":[{"key":"MYCONTRACT_PUBLIC_KEY", "weight":1}], "accounts":[{"permission":{"actor":"mycontract","permission":"eosio.code"},"weight":1}], "waits":[] }' owner -p mycontract`

After this you can sign contract actions as bob and it will transfer the money appropriately

Comment: This is now the error I am getting on the action: Error 3050003: eosio_assert_message assertion failure
Error Details:
assertion failure with message: read

Comment: Good, that means this question is answered and you should post a new question with the new error.

Comment: So every time some one want to send EOS using my contract has to gain permission is this a feasible idea, or eosjs don't need this?

Answer (score 1):

After deploying the smart contract you need to add the following permission:

```
cleos set account permission contract_name active --add-code
```